# in drbd 9 cant parse node-id or connection

Tags: drbd

according to https://linbit.com/drbd-user-guide/drbd-guide-9_0-en/ and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/drbd.conf-9.0.5.html
I'd configured my drbd config . my config:

```
resource c_ssd1_drbd1 {

    device  /dev/drbd1;
    disk    /dev/pool_ssd_1/bd1;
    meta-disk internal;


    on NODE-1 {
            address 172.*.*.120:7701;
            node-id 0;
    }
    on NODE-2 {
            address 172.*.*.121:7702;
            node-id 1;
    }
    on NODE-3 {
            address 172.*.*.122:7703;
            node-id 2;
    }

    connection {
            host NODE-1   port 7701;
            host NODE-2   port 7702;
            net {
                    protocol C;
             }
    }
    connection {
            host NODE-1   port 7701;
            host NODE-3   port 7703;
            net {
                    protocol A;
             }
    }
    connection {
            host NODE-2   port 7702;
            host NODE-3   port 7703;
            net {
                    protocol A;
             }
    }
}
```

when i wanna up my resource c_ssd1_drbd1 with command

```
 drbdadm up c_ssd1_drbd1
```

it shows me this error:

```
  drbdadm up drbd.d/c_ssd1_drbd1.res:10: Parse error: 'disk | device | address |    meta-disk | flexible-meta-disk' expected,
but got 'node-id'
```

and if i comment node-id after that it cant parse connection!!

why?? :((

thanks to help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a DRBD 8 kernel module loaded, then drbdadm parses the configuration in v8 format which doesn't have node-id.

Hope that helps,